# Gitlab included file does not have a valid YAML syntax

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I'm checking `.gitlab-ci.yml` using CI lint, I'm getting following error:

`Included file https://gitlab.ch/Screener/ContinousDelivery/-/raw/master/deployment/.gitlab-ci.yml does not have valid YAML syntax!`

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
include:
  - remote: "https://gitlab.ch/Screener/ContinousDelivery/-/raw/master/deployment/.gitlab-ci.yml"
```

But when I'm checking syntax of `https://gitlab.ch/Screener/ContinousDelivery/-/raw/master/deployment/.gitlab-ci.yml` check pass and status is correct.

Comment: When I view that URL, it is a `0kb` (empty) file. That's probably why.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the include system is particularly robust. You can usually test it by using python or something to try loading the .yml file and seeing what error it produces.